# How to get a substring of a label's string value in swift

Tags: swift, string, substring, swift3

I know that you can access get a substring of a string via:

```
let greeting = "Guten Tag!"
let index = greeting.index(greeting.startIndex, offsetBy: 7)
greeting[index]
```

But what if I don't have a string but instead have a label's stringvalue such as

```
label.stringvalue
```

How do I get a substring of that stringvalue?

Comment: Hint: when typing something like `label.stringvalue` doesn't give anything, use Xcode's autocomplete to find the correct spelling: type `label.str` and hit ESC to see possible completions. Even `label.` + ESC would present a relevant list of possibilities.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like it's just a typo. It should be `stringValue` (upper case `V`).

Comment: Wow you are correct.  I cant believe xcode didn't prompt me to auto correct that.